# Some problems when the interface is stretched

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I create an application interface, the initial state this is what I want, but when I stretch the interface, this happens unexpectedly.

```py
class AllSettingWindow(QWidget):
    submit: QPushButton
    cancel: QPushButton
    result: pyqtSignal = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super(AllSettingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings")
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)
        # layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setObjectName("layout")
        for i in range(1, self.layout.columnCount()):
            self.layout.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 1)
            self.layout.setRowStretch(i, 1)

        self.theme_label = QLabel("theme")
        self.theme_light = QRadioButton("light")
        self.theme_dark = QRadioButton("dark")
        self.theme_auto = QRadioButton("Auto")

        self.font_label = QLabel("fonts")
        self.font_box = QComboBox()
        for i in range(10):
            self.font_box.addItem(str(i))
        self.font_size_label = QLabel("font-size")
        self.font_size_box = QComboBox()
        for i in range(64):
            self.font_size_box.addItem(str(i))

        self.submit = QPushButton("submit")
        self.cancel = QPushButton("cancel")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.theme_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.themes = QButtonGroup()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.theme_light, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.theme_dark, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.theme_auto, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.font_label, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.font_box, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.font_size_label, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.font_size_box, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.submit, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        
        # self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        # self.layout.setRowStretch(self.layout.rowCount(), 1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

When I increased the height, the controls in each row increased with the height and the first row of controls took up a lot of space, which was not the result I wanted, I wanted them to expand in equal proportions

Initial

[image]

Stretched

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Set the vertical policy for the label to `Fixed`:

```
self.theme_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
```

### Explanation

The [`sizePolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) of a widget is what a layout has to know about its behavior when it has to resize and lay out objects.

The vertical [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) is `Preferred`, which means that the widget can be shrunk under or grown beyond the height of its size hint (the suggested preferred size for the widget).

On the other hand, buttons (including QRadioButton) and combo boxes by default have a `Fixed` vertical policy, meaning that they cannot be vertically shrunk as their size hint will *always* be respected.

A grid layout tries to honor the vertical size hint and policy of all widgets inside each row (and the same for the horizontal hint and policy of all columns).
Since a `Fixed` policy is considered more important, the layout will choose to honor it for each row that has a button or combo, even if it also contains a widget with a `Preferred` policy, and since the size hint of the label is considered sufficient to properly show it, it will not grow that row. But since there's also a row with a `Preferred` policy only, it will let that row occupy all the vertical space left by the other rows.

Setting the `Fixed` policy for the first label will cause the layout to have *all* "row policies" as fixed, so it will place them evenly.

### Further notes

- setting the row/column stretch is uneffective for rows that have widgets with a `Fixed` or `Maximum` vertical/horizontal policy;
- even if it would work, you're trying to set the row stretch and minimum height *before* adding any widget to the layout (and you're also trying to do so using the `columnCount()`, which is obviously wrong): at that point there's no row, so the `for` cycle will be ignored;
- the row and column span of a grid layout always defaults to 1, specifying it is unnecessary;
- rows and columns of grid layouts are always 0-based indexed (as almost anything), you should add widgets starting from row and column 0, not 1;
- [`layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) is an existing function of all QWidgets, it's better to avoid overwriting it;